# how to solve unresolved inclusion include <sys/wait.h> on eclipse?

Tags: c, wait, sys

i am writing a code in c on eclipse , i am using the library   ,
but i get this error :

> unresolved inclusion: < sys/wait.h>

i get it in this line :

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

after searching to solve this problem there not a lot of information how to solve this , i think i need to add a path to this library the problem is what is the path to it ? or maybe there is another way ?

thank you in advance.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: i am using windows

Comment: That's probably why you don't have that header, then. It's not a Windows one.

Comment: That doesn't have to be the problem. It is the toolchain selection, and the "Discovery" feature, that might be misleaded. Which toolchain did you choose? Which compiler do you use? What kind of project did you select?